# How to match all numbers on specific html element and save as an attribute in Gatling

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I am trying to understand how regex and syntax work in Gatling. but having a hard time understanding it. In my response body, I have `<a href="display.php?id=195760&amp;userId=416422" tabindex="12">`
and I want to save the id using regex in Gatling.
so far I have tried this, but it does not work. I have anyone have an input to it.

```
regex("""<a href='display.php?id=(\d+)""").saveAs("testId")
```

right now I am getting error

```
regex(<a href='display.php?id=(\d+)).find.exists, found nothing
```

I expected that the regex match the numers inside a tag and save it testId as atribute in Gatling

Answer (score 1):

You're using a single quote in your regex while your actual text contains a double quote. How could it possibly match?